# Is there an openjdk-11-jre?

Tags: java

For Linux distributions, there is a package openjdk-8-jre for installing just the jre part of the openjdk 8.
Is there something familiar for the latest openjdk 11 for windows?
The latest openjdk versions can be downloaded at http://jdk.java.net/11/ but I cannot find a way to download just the jre part.

Comment: @PeterLawrey JDK 11 does not include a JRE sub-directory.

Comment: @Gili Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We don't provide a separate JRE download with JDK 11. Instead, you can use jlink to create a custom runtime image with just the set of modules required by your application. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Strange though - instead of having a jre, people now need a different "jre variant" for each application?  Or we just install everything?  What are the best practices here - minimal package or sharing with others?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now it´s more clear to me.
But the downside is that Java looses its platform independency.

Comment: It depends on your use case. If it requires a single, central runtime installation to service multiple different applications, then you can either install the JDK as is, or use jlink to create a runtime containing just the modules required by all the different applications. For example, if none of them is a desktop application, you could avoid that module altogether. If on the other hand your use case requires the runtime and application to be tightly coupled, then you can use jlink to deliver that outcome, too.

Comment: @DaliborTopic could you say, was it possible for to dowload the JRE separately for JDK 11? Trying to find answer to this question... [When JRE was completely discontinued as a separate offering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868821/when-jre-was-completely-discontinued-as-a-separate-offering)

Answer (score 19):

[Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/releases.html) (previously [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html)) offers  JRE downloads for Java 8 and up.

Comment: I didn't find a JRE in AdoptOpenJDK 11 though. I'm not sure if i'm missing it

Comment: Funny, I have not seen it, although it was offered there. Only with this remark here, I got back to the homepage and had a closer look again - and found it. It is below the JDK in the same box. You easily mistaken it for another JDK download button, same three letters, same blue button, and some Checksum info... You might think it is just another server or something of the like, but it is the JRE.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a web-based tool to make it easier to create a custom JRE from an OpenJDK 11 implementation (such as Oracle HotSpot, Eclipse OpenJ9, or Amazon Corretto) using `jlink`. The tool will give you the correct `jlink` command to run depending on your needs, and this will generate the JRE 11 you're looking for.

I've also included a way to make a standard Java SE JRE 11 for those who just want a basic lightweight (~40-60 MB) JRE. If you know how to use a terminal, it'll take you less than 2 minutes to create a general-use JRE. It works for JDK 9 and up.

You can give it a shot here: https://github.com/justinmahar/easyjre