# How to properly install Oracle Java 8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to install Oracle Java 8 on my Ubuntu 18.04 using packages. I already added the apt-repository, but when trying to install it says package is not available. All I do is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then it says:

```
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Maybe the package has already been deleted and is not available now?

Comment: Normally, you use a package because you want it to be part of updates, etc. But Java 8 is years out of date. If you want to install something that out of date, you're probably best off doing it directly, downloading the installer from Oracle and running it directly, not via `apt`.

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow me to downlaod an installer without registering :( if there was any other source to download it manually, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, I just use throw-away email addresses for that.

Comment: (Well, actually, I use my Oracle account. But in similar situations, I just use a throw-away email.)

Comment: Okay, how to install the Oracle package? I downloaded the tar.gz, then converted to a .deb, installed the package but no java folder was created in /usr/lib/jvm/

Comment: I think this method of installation has been discontinued following Oracle's change of terms on 4/16/2019.
https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have mentioned to install openjdk-8.
After that--->
Get `jfxrt.jar` file from https://github.com/qweasdzxcpoi/JavaFX
Do `sudo nautilus`.
And put it in your `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext`
This personally worked for me when all the other commands were not working for some reason idk.
After that rebuild your project.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, the errors disappeared, Netbeans can now find JavaFX. But when I try to build a Maven project, it fails with the error `Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (unpack-dependencies) on project fx-cca-simul: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/javafxpackager" `

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with that I have no experience of maven projects, just worked on JavaFX. While running my project I did not use maven.

Comment: Do you know where to put the `jfxrt.jar` file in openjdk-11?

Comment: There is no `jre` for `openjdk-11` but there is a bypass wround it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714672/is-there-an-openjdk-11-jre

Comment: I wouldn't trust a JAR from a random GitHub account with a name that just looks like some keys were mashed together.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx` should do the trick.
It will get you JavaFX for OpenJDK.

Read more at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091157/javafx-missing-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I have even openjfx, but my programs still don't work.
```
openjdk-8-jdk is already the newest version (8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1).
openjfx is already the newest version (11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2).
```

Comment: did you set the SDK properly. Read the answers in the link

Comment: I already set the Netbeans settings, but it still cannot find my JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre`. Currently you have only installed an installer.

Comment: I have installed openjdk, but it doesn't support JavaFX. I need Oracle Java 8 for JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

This still works and is enough to run Jenkins.