# When JRE was completely discontinued as a separate offering?

Tags: java, java-9, java-11, java-module, jlink

Starting from Java 9 the module system was introduced, making provision of JRE separately *redundant*.

Through, it seems that it was still possible to download it. For example, from here now [Java 9 archive](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html)
Also, [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) it's only stated that :

> Restructure the JDK and JRE run-time images to draw a clear distinction between files that developers, deployers, and end-users can rely upon and, when appropriate, modify, in contrast to files that are internal to the implementation and subject to change without notice.
>
> The new image structure eliminates this distinction: A JDK image is simply a run-time image that happens to contain the full set of development tools and other items historically found in the JDK.

So no talk about complete removal.
From : [jdk-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installed-directory-structure-jdk-and-jre.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F7178F2F-DC92-47E9-8062-CA6B2612D350)

> When you install jdk-9, public jre-9 also gets installed automatically.

Also, I was thinking that started from Java 9 the custom runtime should be always  created using the jlink, but it seems it's enforced  now only from Java 11.
From the release notes of Java 11 here [Oracle JDK release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html):

> In Windows and macOS, installing the JDK in previous releases optionally installed a JRE. In JDK 11, this is no longer an option.
> In this release, the JRE or Server JRE is no longer offered. Only the JDK is offered. Users can use jlink to create smaller custom runtimes.

But then I can find a lot of discussions like those:

- [Where is Java 9 JRE?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2175168-where-is-java-9-jre)
- [Create jre from OpenJDK Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403071/create-jre-from-openjdk-windows)
- [Why did Java 11 JRE not install with JDK and where is the download for just the Java 11 JRE?](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/9ualdq/why_did_java_11_jre_not_install_with_jdk_and/)
- [Is there an openjdk-11-jre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714672/is-there-an-openjdk-11-jre)

Is this the case and it is not possible to download JRE directly **since Java 11**? Or am I mixing implementations between (Oracle and OpenJDK)? Or were those discussions above misleading?

*Edit: I don't need to download the jre, I could create it via jlink or use already avaialble solution, my question is more of a theoretic*.

Comment: The JDK traditionally included a private JRE.

Comment: you can download JREs from https://adoptopenjdk.net, e.g. for Windows: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_win

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, it's undestandable as it contains the JVM, but my question is more when it's discontinued as a separate offering : )

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion, but I don't need to dowlnoad the jre separately : ) Through, do you know how it works behind the scenes? How jre is created from jdk? (Or is it even so)

Comment: But you asked: "*download of JRE is not possible directly only from Java 11*" - and the answer to that is: yes it's possible to download only the JRE for Java 11. To create a JRE from a JDK `jlink` is used. But if you neither want to download the JRE and you already know it's created with jlink, then what exactly is your question?

Comment: @anasmi Yes, but some of the documentation you've read is about the private JRE inside the JDK.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As far as I understand, it's not possible for Java 11. or where can I you download the JRE separately? (Not to creat by hand via jlink, but download as it was possible with jdk and jre 8) My *assumption/understanding* is that JRE is not comming as a standalone product anymore. (Is this  wrong?) But my original question is from which version it's **not possible**  to dowload it separately 9 or 11? Sorry if I have phrased it's poorly :/

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen could you point me, please, which of this is for the private parts inside the JDK? Maybe it would explain  everything :)

Comment: As I already mentioned: you **can** download a JRE from e.g. https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_win

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to be honest, it's confusing me even more. "*AdoptOpenJDK uses infrastructure, build and test scripts to produce prebuilt binaries from OpenJDK™ class libraries and a choice of either the OpenJDK HotSpot or Eclipse OpenJ9 VM.*" So it's actually a tool that creates the JRE for you. (Not the separate implementation of Java Specification as Oracle and OpenJDK, which JRE's I can't download from the official page). Also, what all of those release notes means then?

Comment: It's not a tool that creates a JRE for you. You can download a JRE from that link.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is this the case and it is not possible to download JRE directly since Java 11?  Or am I mixing implementations between (Oracle and OpenJDK)?

It is correct (mostly).  From Java 11 onwards, neither Oracle JDK or OpenJDK JDK has a corresponding JRE available for public downloads.

**However** (and this is where you are incorrect) other distributors of Java **do** provide JRE downloads (or packages) as an option.  Details may be found via the "Java is still free" link below.

> When JRE was completely discontinued as a separate offering?

It was discontinued for the Oracle and OpenJDK distributions with Java 11.  The Java 11 [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html) state:

> *"In this release, the JRE or Server JRE is no longer offered. Only the JDK is offered. Users can use jlink to create smaller custom runtimes."*

I have not been able to find any earlier public announcements from Oracle about the discontinuance of their JRE releases.  (If someone finds one, please comment ...)

---

Please note:  this is a specific answer to the specific questions asked by the OP.  For more information on the status of Java vis-a-vis licenses, distributions, vendors, support, and whether or not Java is "free", I recommend that you read the following:

- ["Java is still free"](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b) written by the Java Champions community of independent Java leaders and experts.

It is a "live" document, and is likely to remain a good source of up-to-date information; i.e. *more likely to be up-to-date than this Answer!*

Comment: I also could not find any earlier public announcement about this from Oracle. As I recall, 
the change was made with little fanfare, and no advance warning. In the Release Notes you link to I suspect the actual change was implemented by JDK-8185077, as documented in the _"Removal of Java Deployment Technologies"_ section. But even now that bug report is **"not public"**.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the question is incorrect. JRE was not discontinued. It was only discontinued by Oracle. For example, on Linux, JRE is still available*:

```
$ apt-cache search openjdk-11-jre
openjdk-11-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-11-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-11-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero
```

** requires repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa*

Some other JDK providers still offer JRE as well:

- [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jre) offers JRE.
- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html) offers JRE.
- [Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) offers JRE.

Comment: Please note that the "jre" these vendors are offering is absolutely _not_ the same thing as the old JRE. The old JRE was a client side install that added support for Java Web Start and Applets. That has been discontinued as a bundled runtime is now the preferred deployment mechanism (and applets are obsolete)